# How to interruput ajax request but keep for next possible uses?

Tags: 7, javascript, ajax, chaos-tool-suite

I want to add simple confirmation box for ajax delete action created via:
[ctools_ajax_text_button](http://api.drupal.psu.edu/api/drupal/modules!contrib!ctools!includes!modal.inc/function/ctools_modal_text_button/mooc7)

JS:

```
(function ($) {

    Drupal.behaviors.mymod = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {

            Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSend = function (xmlhttprequest, options) {

                if ($(this.element).hasClass(Drupal.settings.mymod.confirm_element_class)) {
                    return confirm(Drupal.t('Please confirm your action'));
                }

                return true;
            }
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

It works, but only first time. When I click delete link and choose Cancel option in modal dialog, next clicking doesn't trigger AJAX action at all on this link, so basically makes ajax action inactive.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by:

```
        Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSend = function (xmlhttprequest, options) {

            if ($(this.element).hasClass(Drupal.settings.mymod.confirm_element_class)) {
                if (!confirm(Drupal.t('Please confirm your action'))) {
                    this.ajaxing = false;
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
```